# post method in ajax request Method Not Allowed in js

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, post

I tried to post method in ajax request Method Not Allowed in js and give me Status Code 405 please help me

// js code

```
        const xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
        xml.onload = function(){
           console.log(this.responseText);
        }
        
        
        xml.open("POST","receive.php",true);
        
        xml.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        
        xml.send("name=kareem&lastvist=Today");
```

// php code

```
        <?php
        foreach ($_POST as $post_var) {
            echo strtoupper($post_var)
        }
        
        ?>
```

Comment: Your `echo` is missing a `;`

Answer (score 0):

The 405 Method Not Allowed error occurs when the web server is configured in a way that does not allow you to perform a specific action for a particular URL. It’s an HTTP response status code that indicates that the request method is known by the server but is not supported by the target resource.

If you calling `XMLHttpRequest().open()` this method for an already active request (one for which open() has already been called) is the equivalent of calling abort().